# Could not edit few fields of page using Facebook Graph API

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I can able to update the page profile info using Graph API with manage_pages permission and as a manager of the page. But I am experiencing the problem in editing the following fields. Can anyone help me.

**name, category(Base and sub category), price range & payment options**

on editing **email & category** it's returning error `Parameters do not match any fields that can be updated`, on **price_range** `Application does not have permission for this action`.

I could not find any permission name to allow **price_range** editing.

Kindly suggest me if there is any other API to edit these fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Currently `Facebook Graph API` supports update for general information. Hope surely Facebook will provide support in the upcoming versions.

**reference** : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/

Answer (score 1):

I think the Graph API doesn't support updates for these fields.

The [Page reference for Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/) says that you can update Page's basic attributes by issuing an HTTP POST request to PAGE_ID with Page Access Tokens. It lists a bunch of arguments that it supports, which are: **about, description, general_info, website, phone.**

Comment: Do you think they may include these in future? or any reasons behind why specifically they do not allow these fields to update via Graph API?

Comment: The API is improving with time. Hope so they include these features in the future. And no, hey haven't mentioned any reason for this limited feature in their documentation.